# Prepositional Phrase vs Participle Phrase

Tags: grammar, adjectives, phrases, prepositional-phrases, participles

Following the meeting, we all had a chat.

In the above sentence, what is Following used as. Is it a adjective or preposition or both?
Also,is following the meeting a prepositional phrase or participle phrase?
Is there any way to identify it?

Comment: It can't be both, obviously! "Following" is a **preposition** here, with a meaning similar to "after". Since the expression has a prep as head, it must be a preposition phrase, functioning as a temporal adjunct.

Answer (score 1):

Following in this case is a preposition making "Following the meeting" a prepositional phrase. It shows the relationship between the meeting and the chat. It shows that the chat happened after the meeting.